# maven cannot download sencha release from central repository (pom packaging)

Tags: maven, extjs, gxt

Maven cannot download   sencha gxt release. I have following in my pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
<groupId>com.sencha.gxt</groupId>
<artifactId>gxt-release</artifactId>
<version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is snippet from my settings.xml

```
      <repository>
                <id>thirdparty-uploads</id>
                <name>JBoss Thirdparty Uploads</name>
                <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-uploads</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
                <id>maven central</id>
                <name>maven central repo</name>
                <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
```

Here is the maven error output

```
  Downloading: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-uploads/com/sencha/gxt/gxt-release/3.0.1/gxt-release-3.0.1.jar
 Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sencha/gxt/gxt-release/3.0.1/gxt-
     release-3.0.1.jar
      Downloading: http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/com/sencha/
        gxt/gxt-release/3.0.1/gxt-release-3.0.1.jar
     Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/sencha/gxt/gxt-release/3.0.
        1/gxt-release-3.0.1.jar
      [ INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [INFO] Reactor Summary:
        [INFO]
      [INFO] xxxx............................................... SUCCESS [0.147s]
   [INFO] yyyyyy ........................................... FAILURE [5.065s]
```

Obviously the links for gxt-release-3.0.1.jar in maven trace above doesnt work.
I downloaded the zip for gxt-release and infact noticed that it doesnt have the file "gxt-release-3.0.1.jar"
Below is the snippet from pom.xml of gxt-release-3.0.1.jar from central repository

```
     <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>gxt-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.sencha.gxt</groupId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>gxt-release</artifactId>
   **<packaging>pom</packaging>** 
  <name>Sencha GXT Release package</name>
  <description>This project represents a full ExtGWT release, available for download by non-maven users. Maven users should make use of the artifacts in central, or the snapshots made available by the ExtGWT team.</description>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
```

My questions are:
1)when packaging type (as highlighted in pom.xml of gxt release above) is pom type, why is maven looking for jar file to download that doesnt exist

2)any clues on what might be causing my maven build/download to fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed to war packaging and it worked

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```